# applying function using group by in Pandas gives the same result for al groups

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a dataframe Table and I want to get the linear regression coefficients for each group (city, category) using Price and Sold data.

```
table = (pd.DataFrame({'city' : ['London', 'London', 'London', 'London', 'Paris', 'Paris'], 'category' : ['boots', 'boots', 'hats', 'hats', 'boots', 'boots'], 'Price':[100, 200, 100, 361, 261, 90], 'Sold':[1,7,  5, 2,  11, 7]}))
```

[image: dataframe]

So I do:

```
def linreg (X, Y):
    linreg = LinearRegression().fit(X,Y)
    const = linreg.intercept_
    slope = linreg.coef_
    return const, slope


X = pd.DataFrame(table[['Price']])
Y = pd.DataFrame(table[['Sold']])

print (table.groupby(['city', 'category']).apply( lambda x: linreg(X, Y)))
```

But as I result I get the same numbers for each group, which is wrong ('cause when I calculate it separately, the results are different):

```
city    category
London  boots       ([5.171956504957155], [[0.0017700188581448472]])
        hats        ([5.171956504957155], [[0.0017700188581448472]])
Paris   boots       ([5.171956504957155], [[0.0017700188581448472]])
```

What am I doing wrong?
As a result I want to have a dataframe like this:

```
City   category Slope const
London boots    1.96   0.52
London hats     0.06    -5
Paris  boots   0.02.    4.8
```

Comment: Use transform instead of apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global variables `X` and `Y`:

```py
X = pd.DataFrame(table[['Price']])
Y = pd.DataFrame(table[['Sold']])
```

Are being used here:

```
.apply( lambda x: linreg(X, Y)))
```

For this reason, the same frames are being passed in and calculated, and the local variable `x` (the current group) is not being used at all. Hence, every group having the same results.

---

Instead, utilize the variable that comes from the `groupby` and pass those `'Price'` and `'Sold'` frames into the `linreg` function.

```py
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

table = (pd.DataFrame({'city': ['London', 'London', 'London',
                                'London', 'Paris', 'Paris'],
                       'category': ['boots', 'boots', 'hats',
                                    'hats', 'boots', 'boots'],
                       'Price': [100, 200, 100, 361, 261, 90],
                       'Sold': [1, 7, 5, 2, 11, 7]}))


def lin_reg(x, y):
    l_reg = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)
    slope = l_reg.coef_[0][0]  # Get Value Instead of Nested List
    const = l_reg.intercept_[0]  # Get Value Instead of List
    return slope, const  # Return in Order they should appear in result table


print(
    table.groupby(['city', 'category'])
        .apply(lambda s:
               # Create Series so results expand into 2 Columns
               pd.Series(
                   lin_reg(
                       s['Price'].to_frame(),
                       s['Sold'].to_frame()
                   ), index=['slope', 'const'])
               )
        .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
     city category     slope     const
0  London    boots  0.060000 -5.000000
1  London     hats -0.011494  6.149425
2   Paris    boots  0.023392  4.894737
```